# Jquery Draggable and sortable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am facing a particular issue with combining draggable and sortable.
I am using Jquery version 1.8.2 drag and drop works fine but I need to use Jquery version 1.11.3 sortable but it is not working.

I don't how to solve the problem. Please correct my mistake.

```
<html >
<head >
    <title></title>

    <script src=" /jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src=" /netjs/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src=" /netjs/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src=" /netjs/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".sortable").sortable({
                revert: true
            });
            $('.draggable').draggable({
                connectToSortable: ".sortable",
                helper: "clone",
                revert: "invalid"
            });
            $("ul, li").disableSelection();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="dbdiv">
                        <ul class="" style="list-style-type: none;">
                             <li>one</li>
                             <li>two</li>
                             <li>three</li>
                             <li>four</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50px;"></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="demo dbdiv">
                        <ul class="sortable dbdiv" style="min-height: 40px; min-width: 170px;">

                             <li>one</li>
                             <li>two</li>
                             <li>three</li>
                             <li>four</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check this link:-https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to implement:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Try it yourself https://jsfiddle.net/k3z0gvut/